# Programming with hardware in python

Tags: python, hardware

I am starting to get a bit bored of programming little toys that I have been making recently, and I would love to starting programming and interacting with hardware.

The only problem is that I am mostly a python guy who hasn't really learned or used any other language. Can I still interact with hardware with python?

Also, what hardware can I interact with? I don't really have stuff lying around that I can use, so I would have to buy a kit or something. What are some cheap options for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interacting with the serial port on a PC is fairly trivial and there is [Python Serial library](http://pyserial.wiki.sourceforge.net/pySerial) available. [The roomba robot is controllable via a serial port](http://www.gorobotics.net/the-news/hobbyiest/irobot-releases-roomba-serial-port-interface). There are probably other robots out there, but this might be a simple, smallish step to get you going.

Personally, I learned a lot by buying [a PIC programmer](http://dkc1.digikey.com/us/en/ph/Microchip/pic32.html) and making some simple [circuits to flash LEDs](http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/rgb-led.html). I moved on to controlling those PICs via serial port and later using USB (via [libusb](http://libusb-win32.sourceforge.net/)). There's a bigger learning curve there as you'll have to program the PICs in C or assembler but you can achieve some pretty incredible results once you've picked up the basics. I warn you though, it's a slippery slope once you realise how many cool little gadgets you can build :-)

Comment: pySerial is fantastic (and refreshingly cross-platform); I've been using it to communicate with the ECU in my car (embedded on-board computer, basically; SuperH architecture) to perform flashing and logging, and it works like a champ. If you're working with more modern hardware without a native serial port, FTDI (http://www.ftdichip.com/) serial-to-usb devices are quite handy; while you can still use pySerial to talk to them, you can also use libftdi (http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/), whose SWIG interface gives a somewhat richer API.

Comment: +1 for the microcontroller idea. It is a good way to start lowlevel in an environment that is still overseeable.

Comment: You can also use USB serial dongles and even USB microcontrollers and still keep talking to them like with an async serial (EIA232) port.

Answer (score 11):

Definitely look at [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/).

- The hardware design is open-source so you could even assemble your own if you wanted
- The board includes digital and analog inputs and outputs so it's easy to get some LEDs flashing quickly
- You program it in a 'language' called [Wiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino#Software) which hides a lot of complexities of C which is usually used on PICs

On the PC side, you could then use pySerial to communicate with the board over USB as mentioned above

Comment: +1: For the mention of Arduino. I was trying to think of the name earlier and couldn't remember it. I've often toyed with the idea of having a go with one though :-)

Answer (score 5):

The new [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) devices have a good range of I/O and Python seems to be the most commonly used language for them.

Answer (score 3):

try [BugLab](http://www.buglabs.net/) or [OpenMoko](http://openmoko.com/)

Comment: "What are some cheap options for this?" Buying a phone is not cheap

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) for interfacing with hardware.  It'll let you call into native libraries, so you can essentially use it to do anything that C can do.  This is of course assuming that you want to interact with hardware via your host computer running Python.

I've used ctypes for a couple of projects:

- [Controlling Keyboard LED on OS X to show morse code](http://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/03/01/5k-morse-code-app-using-capslock-led/)
- Creating USB/HID user-land driver for a [response box](http://www.iolab.co.uk/index.html)

I found it generally pretty easy to use, but it helped that I already knew C/C++.

Comment: +1 for Keyboard LED & morse Code Idea !

Answer (score 2):

Buy a Lego [Mindstorm](http://mindstorms.lego.com/eng/New_York_dest/default.aspx) kit.  The programming language is easy to live with -- it isn't Python -- but it's close enough.  And they're real robots with real actuators and sensors.

Comment: "cheap option" is presumedly relative :)

Answer (score 2):

Many pc's still have parellel ports, and a python module exists for [interacting with the parallel port](http://pyserial.wiki.sourceforge.net/pyParallel), though I haven't used it.

The parallel port may be the simplest way to start controlling hardware, as you can attach the simplest of electronics to it. Just an led will get you something visible straight away.

Then, as Jon Cage mentions, you could get a [Pic programmer](http://www.maplin.co.uk/Module.aspx?ModuleNo=37172)

Comment: +1: You're right, the parallel port is probably simpler to get started with.

Comment: I have used it. Be careful not to overload a port that's difficult to replace. Also, USB parallel ports often aren't. They're hardcoded to drive parallel port printers.

Answer (score 1):

The SNAP wireless nodes at www.synapse-wireless.com run a subset of Python called SNAPpy. You can use the peek() and poke() built-ins in the SNAPpy language to interact directly with hardware inside the chip (PWM for example). SNAPpy also has built-ins for I2C, SPI, and serial, so you can control external hardware. It also has built-ins for lower level I/O too, like readPin() writePin() and readAdc(). Something like an EK2500 kit might be good to start with. See also the online user forum at forums.synapse-wireless.com

Comment: Only price I found: $180. Ouch, even for a devkit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure anyone has mentioned the BASIC stamp.  Again - it is very limited, but its SUPER simple to start working with.  There are some other processors up there they make too, but as an introductory - I think its a great device.

Arduino too is a good one, and you can probably get more bang for you buck with that device.

As mentioned above, I got my start on PIC processors - which are not the easiest thing to work with initially (or really ever... haha - its debateable), but I got a great understanding of how things work in the world of micro controller / hardware interaction.

Best of luck & if you have any questions, feel free to ask away!

Comment: I also started on BASIC stamp years ago, but I think its a poor representation of what modern microcontrollers can actaully do. Not to mention how ridiculously expensive the kits are!