# accessing and manipulating hardware using python

Tags: python, hardware

So I am trying to learn how to have a program access other nonintegrated hardware devices (such as an RFID). What I do not quite understand is how the program can access the device's interal functions. Is there a certain library/libraries needed to do so or is using/creating hardware drivers needed?

For the project that I am working on currently, I basically am trying to have the program use a device's various functions in certain situations. For example, how would I request the program to change the song on an ipod or to pause it? This is assuming the ipod has a wired connection to the computer already.

For my actual project, I will be incorporating a speech recognition program (later on, I will make my own. For now I will be using Dragonfly). So, when I say certain commands, it would need to tell the device to act on that command such as telling a home integration system to turn of the lights in the house or electric door lock to lock/unlock.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of existing library which already interfaces with the hardware (like the home integration system), and an API which allows you to address it. If you're lucky they have a python API already, if not you'll need to integrate through C.

[Programming with hardware in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919857/programming-with-hardware-in-python) may also have some pointers, depending on your interface. For example, if it's through a serial port, there are Python libraries to deal with that. Life would also be easier with an Arduino, too, as there has been a lot more done with it since the original question was asked back in '09.